# How to access constants in Angularjs Template

Tags: angularjs, global-variables, constants

How do I access constants defined in common js file into template of different module.

if I have defined a constant like this in my MainModule.js which is included in the beginning of the main html file

```
> var myApp = angular.module('AC' .....);
> myApp.constant('timeoutValue',5);
```

I was able to access my constant in my controller.js by passing "timeoutValue" to it. 
But I am unable to access it in my template.html/partial.

How can I access "timeoutValue" in my template.html/partial file

Answer (score 5):

Inject it into your controller and set a scope variable to it.

```
app.constant('timeoutValue', 5);

app.controller('someController', function($scope, timeoutValue) {
  $scope.timeoutValue = timeoutValue;
});
```

Comment: Ya i am doing like this now but i dont want to assign to local scope variable. Is there a way to access "timeoutValue" directly in template.html?

Comment: No, the view interacts with the scope and controllers. Controllers interact with services and scope. View does not interact directly with services.

Comment: I guess one way to get around this would be to assign the value in $rootScope. I prefer the approach in my answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign constant to $rootScope and use in template.

```
myModule.constant('brand', 'MyBrand');
myModule.run(['$rootScope','brand', function ($rootScope,brand) {
    $rootScope.brand = brand;
}]);
```