# Displaying constants within directive view after successfully injecting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

question regarding `constants` within angularjs.  I have the following constants created within `app.js`:

```
 ...     angular
        .module('blocTime', ['firebase', 'ui.router'])
        .config(config)
        .constant('STOP_WATCH', {
          "workTime": 1500,
          "breakTime": 300
        });
})();
```

I've injected the constant inside my directive as follows:

```
(function() {
    function clockTimer($interval, $window, STOP_WATCH) {
        return {
            templateUrl: '/templates/directives/clock_timer.html',
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

                console.log(STOP_WATCH.workTime); ...
...   
 angular
        .module('blocTime')
        .directive('clockTimer', clockTimer);
```

I can console log the constant from my directive just fine.  However, my view is not rendering the constant.  HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="stop-watch">{{ STOP_WATCH.workTime }}</div>
```

It comes back as undefined.  Thoughts as to why or how to make it display in the view?  Thanks

Comment: You could refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39430848/2435473) to fix your problem

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It didn't answer my question, but helped me ask what I needed in several different ways.  Found what I needed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338261/how-to-access-constants-in-angulajs-template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Within my directive I had to add `scope.STOP_WATCH = STOP_WATCH`:

```
(function() {
    function clockTimer($interval, $window, STOP_WATCH) {
        return {
            templateUrl: '/templates/directives/clock_timer.html',
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

scope.STOP_WATCH = STOP_WATCH;
...
```